# iframe isn't picking up src

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat table with the following lines

```
  1. <td>
       <a href="/pdf_viewer/web/viewer.html?file=/pdf/{{x.file_id}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </td>
  2. <td>
       <iframe src="/pdf_viewer/web/viewer.html?file=/pdf/{{x.file_id}}" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
     </td>
  3. <td>
       <iframe src="/pdf_viewer/web/viewer.html?file=/pdf/test.pdf" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
     </td>
```

The 1st and 3rd row show me what i want but the **2nd** row throws me the following error:

```
  Error: $interpolate:noconcatMultiple Expressions
```

When i hardcode the name, it seems to work(i get the same value for all rows which is not what i want but at least it seems to work this way), but when i try to iterate through ng-repeat it shows the error.

Comment: It could be the slashes in the url?

Comment: my x.file_id returns test.pdf .. so, i am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

In Controller:

```
$scope.getIframeSrc = function (fileid) {
  return '/pdf_viewer/web/viewer.html?file=/pdf/' + fileid;
};
```

HTML:

```
ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(x.file_id)}}"
```